# Avoid trapping by ssh ProxyCommand

Tags: ssh, proxy

I have the following lines in my `.ssh/config`:

```
Host localhost
ProxyCommand none
Host n0*
ProxyCommand none

Host *
ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy.m.com 80 myserv 443 ~/.ssh/auth
```

i.e. for `localhost` and `n0*` ssh will not use the proxy, but for other hosts it will.

I got trapped several times know when I wanted to connect to other **local machines**, but couldn't connect because the proxy was active. There was no exception for them in `~/.ssh/config`.

Is there away to echo an information to the command line, when the proxy is used? e.g.

```
$ ssh otherpc
  ---> using  ProxyCommand corkscrew proxy.m.com 80 myserv 443 ~/.ssh/auth
Password:
```

I know that `ssh -v` is listing this line (along with many others):

```
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec corkscrew proxy.m.com 80 myserv 443 ~/.ssh/auth
```

Is there less verbose way of displaying the proxy command used, helping me to avoid being trapped? Maybe a clever bash alias/function grepping `ssh -v`?

*Warning:* Don't write `ssh() { ssh -v | grep Proxy}`. I tried that too ... and accidently *fork bombed* me :P

Comment: what about ssh -oProxyCommand None otherpc ?

Comment: If I typed that, I would be aware that the proxy is active. The point is, however, that I tend to forget the rules I set and can't figure out why I can't logon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you write a small wrapper `corkscrew-wrapper` containing something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Executing proxy command corkscrew ..." > /dev/tty
exec corkscrew "$@"
```

and use `corkscrew-wrapper` instead of `corkscrew` in the ProxyCommand line.

If you want to support execution by `at` or cron, the following should work:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd() { echo "Executing proxy command corkscrew ..."; }

{ cmd > /dev/tty; } 2> /dev/null
[ $? -eq 0 ] || cmd >&2

exec corkscrew "$@"
```

Note: do not detect the availability of `/dev/tty` with the `tty` command because the terminal is not necessarily connected to the standard input.

Comment: excellent idea! (why didn't I think of this myself...?) Looks like it's working. I will not accept immediately in order to encourage alternatives answers.

Comment: Follow up question: when launching from **cron**, `/dev/tty` is not available. The command works nonetheless, but the warning `line 2: /dev/tty: No such device or address` appears.

Comment: @Sebastian I've completed my answer. You may also want to use `>&2` in all cases, but `/dev/tty` may be more reliable when available (and the standard error may have been redirected).

Comment: Sir, you're a master *and* a teacher, and since I cannot upvote twice, I'll immediately accept your answer, despite my earlier claim. My sincere thanks!